# PHP Form Builder - How to Send Email

Tags: php, forms, sendmail

I am using this [PHP form builder](http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/) class but I think I'm missing the very basic which is how to send the email. I know enough php to download and modify the code but not quite sure how to implement:

```
mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)
```

Does anyone know how to get this working and send the email to myself when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), or better use some abstracted class like [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Swiftmailer will save you some hassle down the line, as it sets the headers correctly and is independant from the mail subsystem.

[Here is a basic example how to  include swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html)

Comment: Swift seems a little complicated for me

Comment: @Dony: It's not that complicated, I've added a link to a very basic example.

Comment: @konsolenfreddy aha much better ...they have a lot more documentation which helps me figure it out. I will download it to my localhost and see how it works

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to implement the `mail` function, it should [already be there](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and it has been there by default since PHP 4.

If you're not finding a `mail` function (or if it is not working), then chances are that you are not running on a machine where PHP has access to the sendmail command. You can read about the requirements of the mail function [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php). If this is the case (and you *have* to be able to test the emails), then you will need to get a mail server. If you're on Windows, I know that XAMPP comes with one, but I normally do that sort of development with a Linux box.

Comment: Yes I understand the mail function but Im dont know where its located in this app or where do I modify it so I can change it to my email

Comment: It is part of the [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/searchframe#VgQXDVS9j6M/trunk/includes/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php) class.